# How to display link in Razor view if query string contains certain parameter?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I go to to index view of `ReportsController` sometimes I get link like this:

```
http://localhost:17697/Reports
```

sometimes like this depending from where I came from:

```
http://localhost:17697/Reports?personId=15
```

I would like to display this button:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Back to person", "Person", new { id = PERSON_ID_FROM_QUERYSTRING }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" })
```

if the `?personId`is is present in(is part of) the link.

How to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A URL parameter can be accessed on the `Request` property.

So you can check for this specific request `Request["personId"]`, and if is not null, write the action:

```
@{
    string pid = Request["personId"];
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pid)) {
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to person", "Person", new { id = pid }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are aware of this and are simply trying to avoid doing this in controller, but just for completeness I'll include what is usually the common practice for retrieving query string params in MVC:

```
public class HomeController {

    public ActionResult Reports(int? personId) // this indicates optional query string param
    {
        vm = new ReportsViewModel{ PersonId = personId; };
        vm.Reports = Repository.GetReports();
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

**CSHTML:**

```
@if( Model.PersonId != null)
{
    Html.ActionLink("Back to person", "Person", new { id = Model.PersonId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming PersonId is part of your model, you can reference it in your view:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to person", "Person", new { id = Model.PersonId }, 
                 new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-xs" })
```

Comment: It is not part of my model. It is only part of my query strinh. If it was part of my model I could check it if it is null.

Comment: You could always add it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RouteData dictionary like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to person", "Person", new { id = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["personId"]}
```

For more complex scenarios, have a look at [this post](http://www.zvolkov.com/clog/2012/04/01/asp-net-mvc-build-url-based-on-current-url/).

Comment: Yes, but how to check if the query parameter exists?

Comment: You need to check if the dictionary contains a value for the given key. This would also work with Request.Querystring. I would suggest performing the check in the controller and passing a boolean value to the view by using the view model, or simply updating the model's PersonId property